OTA in AOSP build
I have developed an app with system permissions that downloads a .zip file from an Android 14 R33 build.
The app downloads the file to /data/ota_packages/update.zip.
Then I perform a RecoverySystem.VerifyPackage and the method returns correct.
Next I perform a RecoverySystem.installpackage and using logcat I verify that Android accesses that file and decrypts it using uncrypt.
The problem occurs as soon as the device is restarted in recovery mode and the ota is not installed because the following error is observed in the recovery:
libfs_mgr unknow volume for path /cache/recovery/block.map

Help!!!

Using recovery to install an Android OS update is unusual these days. Ever since launching new devices running Android 8 we are using A/B partitions and update_engine to install updates while the system is running and recovery is not involved. Are you not using A/B partitions? See https://source.android.com/docs/core/ota/ab

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Hi Satur9nine. After reading the documentation the documentation he believed that the RecoverySystem update mode was still in use. It is not clear to me how incorporate the code to use  update_engine into my application. My application runs with system permissions. I can`t import the android.os.UpdateEngine class. Thanks!

I added an answer with suggestion to learn from LineageOS sample updater.

LineageOS kindly provides a sample app demonstrating how to interact with AOSP update_engine to install an OS OTA: https://github.com/LineageOS/android_bootable_recovery/tree/lineage-21.0/updater_sample
You could copy this app source into your AOSP tree to study it.

Thanks for the help. Finally, I implemented the update_engine code to update with a .zip file that I downloaded from my server. All this with an application with platform permissions. Thank you.

@Dani Great, welcome! Click the checkmark to accept this answer if it works for you.
